# Prove recurrence for compositions of $n$ with only odd parts

Tags: combinatorics

Given that $a_n$ is the number of compositions of $n$ with only odd parts, I am trying to prove the recurrence $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$.  I can't come up with a way to show this.  I am looking for some hint on how to classify each of $a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ but haven't come up with anything meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for each composition of $n$, namely {$x_1,x_2,...,x_k$} think about the following two cases:

(1) The first element $x_1$ is 1, then {$x_2,...,x_k$} is a composition of $n-1$

(2) The first element $x_1 \geq2$, then {$x_1-2,x_2,...,x_k$} is a composition of $n-2$. Note that $x_1-2=0$ is not possible as it is odd.

For the only if part:

(1) For each composition of $n-1$, namely {$y_1,y_2,...,y_p$}, we generate {1,$y_1,y_2,...,y_p$} which is a composition of $n$.

(2) For each composition of $n-2$, namely {$z_1,z_2,...,z_q$}, we generate {$z_1 + 2,z_2,...,z_q$} which is a composition of $n$.

The two cases will not share any common element because the first element is different.